# Handling "<5" Values in a Count Column for Case Rate Computation

Tags: data-analysis

I am preparing data for spatial correlation analysis. In one column I have integer values '<5' and values ranging from 5 to 2321.
[image: Example]

The values represent counts of cases that I intend to use with the population column to get a case rate. What is the appropriate way to deal with the '<5' observations?

Comment: Sorry, this is too vague to be answerable.  I don't know what you mean by "deal with".  Your goals are unclear.  We need you to articulate a problem in a way that every reader can understand what is being asked.  It might help to define what is the question you are trying to answer or the value you are trying to compute.  It might also help to provide some background about what you're trying to accomplish, e.g., what is a "case rate", why your observation is "<5" rather than a number like "3", etc.  Are you sure this is a question about mathematics, rather than about statistics?